# Reset sorting at DataGridView event

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to reset my sorting everytime I choose different column how can I achieve this in the code

```cs
private void AdvancedDataGridView_SortStringChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.bindingDBSource.Sort = this.advancedDataGridView.SortString;
}
```

Comment: You can subscribe to the `SelectionChanged` event of the DataGridView and reset your filter in that way

Comment: it sounds like you would need an event that fires when you click a [column header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadermouseclick?view=netframework-4.8)